# How to avoid the divs disorganizing when resizing the window in Tailwind?

Tags: css, typescript, tailwind-css

Hello I've got a website in typescript  [image: website]
that messes up when I'm resizing the window, ending up like this:
[image]

how do I avoid resizing and modifying these, independent of the window size?
Neither flex-wrap or flex-no-wrap worked

Code for the button that resizes

```
<div className="flex-shrink-0 pt-6 text-center w-full justify-items-center items-center">
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="flex-shrink-0 items-center xl:px-40 xl:py-2 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-full text-white bg-sentient-blue hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-sentient-blue-900 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Sign Up
                      </button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the class `flex-shrink-0` on both containing tags to prevent them from shrinking.

1. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-shrink
2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. I'll update my code in the post

Answer (score 0):

flex-flow is a shorthand for the flex-direction and flex-wrap properties, which together define the flex container’s main and cross axes. The default value is row nowrap

Try to assign `flex-flow:column wrap`  to parent

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. I'll update my code in the post